# Monitor IP for RBLs

Tags: monitoring, email-server, rbl

Is there any way to monitor an IP against RBLs. I want to have an alert over email when my IP is blacklisted in any RBL over internet.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We currently use PRTG Network Monitor, they have a sensor to monitor multiple blacklist servers.

[image]

Comment: Is there not any way to configure monitor other than prtg? I want to monitor with Linux, any utility which could configure in Linux. Please let me know.

Comment: sorry, am not too familiar with what is available using Linux packages...

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of services that offer this service. [MXToolbox](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/services_servermonitoring.aspx) and [DNSstuff](https://www.dnsstuff.com/bc-mon-alerts) are two that come to mind.